# How to set different color in listing?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I want to split the listing into three different colors. How to do it? 
[image]

I have read [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59616/problem-with-alignment-in-listings/59629#59629) and apply it like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\color{DarkSlateGray}\small,
texcsstyle=\bf\color{Aquamarine},
identifierstyle=\color{Crimson}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{brown}\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
escapeinside=<>,{},
keywordstyle=\color{teal},
stringstyle=\color{brown}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{cyan},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={$,\{ ,\} , [ , ], & },
moretexcs={maketitle, subsection, subsubsection, appendix, tableofcontents,includegraphics},
}

\begin{document}
\section*{How to set different color in listing}
\begin{lstlisting}
\perintahbeamer[<argumen opsional>]{<argumen pertama>}{<argumen kedua>}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is very short and vague, despite the picture. What exactly do you mean by "split the listing into three different colors"?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174793/how-can-i-mimic-the-output-of-syntax-macros-marg-oarg-etc-without-using-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really clarify your question, but here is my shot at an answer. Is that what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\color{DarkSlateGray}\small,
texcsstyle=\bf\color{Aquamarine},
identifierstyle=\color{Crimson}\bfseries,
moredelim=[s][\color{ForestGreen}]{\{}{\}},
moredelim=[s][\color{blue}]{[}{]},
keywordstyle=\color{teal},
stringstyle=\color{brown}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{cyan},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={$,\& },
moretexcs={maketitle, subsection, subsubsection, appendix, tableofcontents,includegraphics},
}

\begin{document}
\section*{How to set different color in listing}
\begin{lstlisting}
\perintahbeamer[<argumen opsional>]{<argumen pertama>}{<argumen kedua>}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```